# Deploying Dynamic Nuxt Application

Tags: firebase, deployment, nuxt.js, tailwind-css, web-development-server

I'm currently working on deploying a Nuxt application to production. The application relies on Firebase and Tailwind for seamless navigation and clean aesthetics, using API requests to interact with the application. However, I've encountered an issue where after building the application with npm run build and running it in production with npm run start, the Tailwind CSS doesn't seem to be integrated, resulting in a non-css static appearance.

Output after running `npm run start`
[image]

To ensure continuous running of the application, we will be utilizing PM2. It's worth noting that the application functions properly when run in development mode (npm run dev). This leads me to suspect that there may be an issue during the building phase of the application.

Here is the provided nuxt.config.ts for reference:

```
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    runtimeConfig: {
        firebaseApiKey: 'xxx',
        firebaseAuthDomain: 'xxx',
        firebaseDatabaseURL:
      'xxx',
  },
    build: {
        transpile: [
            '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome',
            '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core',
            '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons',
    ],
  },
    css: ['~/assets/css/main.css', '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css'],
    modules: ['@pinia/nuxt'],
    postcss: {
        plugins: {
            tailwindcss: {},
            autoprefixer: {},
    },
  },
    typescript: {
        typeCheck: true,
  },
})
```

I have already gone through a considerable amount of documentation, but I didn't find it particularly useful. It would be greatly appreciated if someone could assist me.

I have provided two pictures of the landing page below. The first one is the production version, and the second one is the development version.

[image]

[image]

Already tried to modify the nuxt.config.ts, to incorporate for example the tailwind. But did not manage to get it working.